# Word for a contemptuous person?

Tags: epithet-requests, diction

Is there a good word for someone who shows contempt for others? Especially when it's a pattern, and anyone who threatens that person's self esteem is held in contempt?

The first thought that comes to mind is, Person X is a contemptuous person. But the word "contemptuous" is a little unwieldy. If you're trying to sum up this attitude neatly in a single word or phrase, it doesn't seem to suffice.

Comment: What politeness register are we talking about here? One of the most common way to describe a contemptuous person is to say that person is a "dick".

Comment: Contempt as a form of vindictive behavior is often triggered by wounded pride.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Equally unwieldy is *[supercilious](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/us/definition/american_english/supercilious)*

> Behaving or looking as though one thinks one is superior to others

*Oxford Dictionaries Online*

Or

> - condescending
> - haughty
> - imperious
> - prideful
> - sniffy
> - swaggering
> - disdainful
> - lordly
> - overbearing
> - arch
> - patronizing
> - snooty

Answer (score 1):

Would these work : Condescend, deride, belittle

Comment: Ah, but those are verbs. I'm looking for a noun or adjective. Such as, "contemptuous", "condescending", "belittling", "narcissist".

Comment: Derider is a person  who derides or belittles

Answer (score 1):

I'd suggest,

***high-hat***

> : having or showing the insulting attitude of people who think that they are better, smarter, or more important than other people : snooty.
>
> [M-W](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/high%E2%80%93hat)

***stuck-up***

> : acting unfriendly toward other people because you think you are better than they are.
>
> [M-W](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/stuck-up)

Answer (score 1):

Such a person is a ***misanthrope***.

Wikipedia gives a good definition:

> Misanthropy is the general hatred, distrust or contempt of the human species or human nature. A **misanthrope** or misanthropist is someone who holds such views or feelings. The word's origin is from the Greek words μῖσος (misos, "hatred") and ἄνθρωπος (anthrōpos, "man, human"). The condition is often confused with asociality.